# Access Azure Public IP inside of Linux VM

Tags: linux, azure, ip, virtual-machine

I have created a Ubuntu 16.04LTS VM on Azure and I need to access its public facing IP in order to configure the docker container I am trying to run on the server.  However, when I do the command below from the terminal in the VM:

```
ip addr show
```

I only get back the private local IP's and not the public facing IP.  What steps do I need to take to access the public IP from the VM's terminal?

The reason I would like to be able to script the getting of the public IP is that we are running a docker container on the VM (we are creating multiple VM's, part of a load testing framework we are developing in JMeter) and if we can script getting the IP and passing it to the docker container in the server startup script, then we would be able to automate our server startup so that the jmeter-server runs properly with the correct IP when we press start server from the Azure portal.  Without being able to access the public IP from a bash script, we would have to manually SSH into each machine and run docker and pass in the public IP as a parameter to docker to start each jmeter server, which would be much more time consuming.

Comment: you'd need to hit some outside url to tell you what the IP the connection came from is, e.g, hit a "what is my ip" site. maybe azure has a webservice you can hit to tell you that, without needing to go "way outside".

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I've spent the last hour or two pouring through Azure's docs and it doesn't seem like they have something like this.  Based on your advice I was able to find "http://www.linuxtrainingacademy.com/determine-public-ip-address-command-line-curl/", and then running "curl ifconfig.me" was able to get me my public ip.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There is this **VM metadata** thing in both AWS and Azure:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/what-just-happened-to-my-vm-in-vm-metadata-service/

but currently there's very little information returned by that feed:

```sh
UbuntuInJapan:~$ curl -s http://169.254.169.254/metadata/latest/InstanceInfo

{"ID":"_UbuntuInJapan","UD":"0","FD":"0"}
```

...just the upgrade and fault domain which are useless for your endeavor.

For Public IP this is what I usually do:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

PUBLIC_IP=$(curl -s http://checkip.amazonaws.com || printf "0.0.0.0")
# Then you either get the public IP address in the variable or you get 0.0.0.0
# which means you could not make the call to Amazon or Amazon is under DDoS.
# amirite?

# Uncomment to echo (AKA debug mode)
echo $PUBLIC_IP
```

You could chain multiple *What is my ip?* services to increase your SLA.
i.e.:

```sh
# First one that works wins.
# You can improve this by regex checking the output.
#
# Something like:
#
# if [[ $PUBLIC_IP =~ [[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\/ ]]
#     then echo 'Good. Valid IPv4. Continue.'
#     else echo 'Bad. Stop.'
# fi

UbuntuInJapan:~$ curl -s http://checkip.amazonaws.FAILS || curl -s http://canihazip.com/s

13.78.92.21
```

Some services will return IPv6 if you talk IPv6 to them, make sure you explicitly pass address family to `curl`:

```sh
$ curl -4 http://l2.io/ip
13.78.92.21

$ curl -6 http://l2.io/ip
2a02:2f0b:4xxx:fxxx:4xxx:xxxx:xxxx:1072
```

Comment: `curl ifconfig.co` if you need one more :D.

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, following works:

```
curl -s -H Metadata:true \
http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance?api-version=2017-04-02 \
| jq -r .network.interface[].ipv4.ipAddress[].publicIpAddress
```

Answer (score 0):

The following does not require jq

```
curl -s -H Metadata:true --noproxy "*" \
"http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance?api-version=2021-02-01" | \
 grep -oP --regexp='"publicIpAddress":"\K([[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3})'
```